# Using cpulimit on an executeable

Tags: server, cpulimit

Is there way to limit cpu on an executeable whenever it is run?

i am trying to use **cpulimit** like :

> cpulimit -e helm -l 50

but i'm getting this:

> Warning: no target process found. Waiting for it...

All the examples i found online are not helping me as they are talking about either a running process or a command about to run. I on the otherhand want to limit cpu to an exe when it is run in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Call your `cpulimit`ed command from a `bash` script, and use that script in your scripting.

E.g., create `$HOME/bin/whelm`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cpulimit -l 20 helm
```

Be sure to `chmod +x $HOME/bin/whelm`.